# User roles: node.js express sequelize react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

I am using this tutorial on bezkoder to create user roles. However, by default the user is given role: 1 [subscriber] during sign-up.
I'm new to a lot of this, so I'm not sure how much I need to change in order to create two sign-up pages: one that will automatically register a user with the role 1 [subscriber] and one that will automatically register a user with the role 2 [expert].

front-end
https://bezkoder.com/react-jwt-auth/

back-end
https://bezkoder.com/node-js-jwt-authentication-mysql/

I think the role is being automatically registered as 1 here in the controller, but I'm not even certain this is where the role is being recorded. Any help much appreciated.

```
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  // Save User to Database
  User.create({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8)
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (req.body.roles) {
        Role.findAll({
          where: {
            name: {
              [Op.or]: req.body.roles
            }
          }
        }).then(roles => {
          user.setRoles(roles).then(() => {
            res.send({ message: "User was registered successfully!" });
          });
        });
      } else {
        // user role = 1
        user.setRoles([1]).then(() => {
          res.send({ message: "User was registered successfully!" });
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After skimming through the provided Frontend tutorial, I think I can narrow the problem down to the component **Authservice**. It has a method named *register*:

```
  register(username, email, password) {
    return axios.post(API_URL + "signup", {
      username,
      email,
      password
    });
  }
```

Because currently you never send a *role* when the user registers. So new users always end up with the default role. If you would want to give the user another role than the default one at registration, you would have to add the parameter *roles* to the config object in the *axios.post* function. For example like this:

```
  register(username, email, password) {
    return axios.post(API_URL + "signup", {
      username,
      email,
      password,
      roles=[ "ROLE_ADMIN" ]
    });
  }
```

So you could create another signup page where you use this modified *register* function instead of the default one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, that is exactly what I needed to know